# Click div to make sound AND the same div is linked to keyboard sound... is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am making a drumkit. The key functionality is that you must be able to click a div on the screen to produce a drum-sound. At the same time, this div should be responsive to pressing a key which makes that same sound.

I can only do one or the other. I want to know if the current code I have written can have additional functionality.

```js
function playSound(e) {
  const audio = this.document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  if (!audio) return; //stop function from running altogether
  audio.currentTime = 0; //rewind to the start
  audio.play();
  key.classList.add('playing');
}

function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; //skip it if its not a transform
  this.classList.remove('playing')
}
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
```

```css
.key {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all 0.07s;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='keys'>
  <div data-key='65' class="key">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="83" class="key">
    <kbd>S</kbd>
    <span class="sound">hihat</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="68" class="key">
    <kbd>D</kbd>
    <span class="sound">kick</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="70" class="key">
    <kbd>F</kbd>
    <span class="sound">openhat</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="71" class="key">
    <kbd>G</kbd>
    <span class="sound">boom</span>
  </div>
</div>

<audio data-key='65' src="./sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="./sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="./sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="70" src="./sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="71" src="./sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I expect to be able to click each div to produce the same sound as if I had pressed the key it is linked to.

Comment: so add click event, read the data attribute,

Comment: Can you show me what that would look like? I'm not sure what is meant by 'read the data attribute'

Comment: `data-key="70"` the attribute

Comment: How do you do it though? How could you include that in my current set up? Do I have to create a new function?

Answer (score 0):

I would add the 'click' event listener to your Keys (the key elements you already loop through) and assign it your play sound function... but then you would need to handle that change in the playSound function better. Instead of cramping a condition in playSound, I would split the code in multiple functions.

Here's how:

```js
function onKeyClicked(e) {
  playSound(e.getAttribute("data-key"));
}

function onKeyPressed(e) {
  playSound(e.keyCode);
}

function playSound(keyCode) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);
  if (!audio) return; //stop function from running altogether
  audio.currentTime = 0; //rewind to the start
  audio.play();
  key.classList.add('playing');
}

function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; //skip it if its not a transform
  this.classList.remove('playing')
}
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => {
  key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition);
  key.addEventListener('click', function() {
    onKeyClicked(key)
  });
});
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPressed);
```

```css
.key {
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:1rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 1rem .5rem;
    transition: all 0.07s;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}

.playing {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-key='65' class="key">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="83" class="key">
    <kbd>S</kbd>
    <span class="sound">hihat</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="68" class="key">
    <kbd>D</kbd>
    <span class="sound">kick</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="70" class="key">
    <kbd>F</kbd>
    <span class="sound">openhat</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="71" class="key">
    <kbd>G</kbd>
    <span class="sound">boom</span>
  </div>
</div>

<audio data-key='65' src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1971&type=wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="83" src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=818&type=wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="68" src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2218&type=wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="70" src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1455&type=wav"></audio>
<audio data-key="71" src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1446&type=wav"></audio>
```

... included some sounds :-)